# Use resizableImageWithCapInsets on SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uiedgeinsets

I'm currently trying to use a stretchable image on a SKSpriteNode.

Typically, strechable images are returned by the method `UIImage::resizableImageWithCapInsets:`

So i wrote that code:

```
SKTexture * texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:[image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 10)]];
SKSpriteNode * node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture size:CGSizeMake(150, 8)];
```

But it don't work. The node streaches itself without taking Edge Insets into account. Is it only possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `centerRect` property of `SKSpriteNode`. Assuming your texture is 50 pixels wide and you want not to stretch the leftmost and rightmost 10 pixels:

```
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImage:image];
SKSpriteNode *node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture size:CGSizeMake(150, 8)];
node.centerRect = CGRectMake(10 / 50.0, 0, 30 / 50.0, 1);
```

`centerRect` is specified in unit coordinates of the texture. More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW10) under "Resizing a Sprite."